# Proving that two determinants are equal without expanding them

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So I need to prove that

> $$
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>     \sin^2(\alpha) & \cos(2\alpha) & \cos^2(\alpha) \\
>     \sin^2(\beta) & \cos(2\beta) & \cos^2(\beta) \\
>     \sin^2(\gamma) & \cos(2\gamma) & \cos^2(\gamma) \\
>     \end{vmatrix}
> $$
>   $$
> = \begin{vmatrix}
>     \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & \sin(\alpha + \delta) \\
>     \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta + \delta) \\
>     \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) & \sin(\gamma + \delta) \\
>     \end{vmatrix}
> $$

Now, 
$$
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \sin^2(\alpha) & \cos(2\alpha) & \cos^2(\alpha) \\
    \sin^2(\beta) & \cos(2\beta) & \cos^2(\beta) \\
    \sin^2(\gamma) & \cos(2\gamma) & \cos^2(\gamma) \\
    \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
    \sin^2(\alpha) & \cos^2(\alpha) - \sin^2(\alpha) & \cos^2(\alpha) \\
    \sin^2(\beta) & \cos^2(\beta) - \sin^2(\beta) & \cos^2(\beta) \\
    \sin^2(\gamma) & \cos^2(\gamma) - \sin^2(\gamma) & \cos^2(\gamma) \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Adding column $1$ to column $2$ then makes column $2$ and column $3$ equal and hence the first determinant $ = 0$.

I'm stuck in trying to prove that the second determinant is also zero, so I need help in that.

Comment: Expand $\sin(\alpha+\delta)$, note relation to first two columns.

Comment: @Gerry I tried doing that, however it didn't lead me anywhere. What do I do after that?

Comment: What did you get when you expanded $\sin(\alpha+\delta)$?

Comment: $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\delta) + \sin(\delta)cos(\alpha)$. Still kind of confused as to how to use the relation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & \sin(\alpha + \delta) \\
    \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta + \delta) \\
    \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) & \sin(\gamma + \delta) \\
    \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & \sin\alpha\color{red}{\cos\delta}+\color{red}{\sin\delta}\cos\alpha \\
    \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & \sin\beta\color{red}{\cos\delta}+\color{red}{\sin\delta}\cos\beta \\
    \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) & \sin\gamma\color{red}{\cos\delta}+\color{red}{\sin\delta}\cos\gamma \\
    \end{vmatrix}$$$${}$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & \sin\alpha \\
    \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & \sin\beta\\
    \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) & \sin\gamma \\
    \end{vmatrix}\color{red}{\cos\delta}+\begin{vmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & \cos\alpha \\
    \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) & \cos\beta\\
    \sin(\gamma) & \cos(\gamma) & \cos\gamma \\
    \end{vmatrix}\color{red}{\sin\delta}=0+0=0$$

Comment: I completely forgot about that property, thank you.

Comment: ...but that's precisely the property you used to prove that the first determinant equals $0$...

Comment: Servaes is right. More than forget that property I think all those sines and cosines together confused you.

Comment: @Servaes I meant the one where you can make two determinants from one by splitting the elements of a column or row

Comment: @DonAntonio That's probably it, thanks anyways.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you meant you used
$$\begin{vmatrix}\sin^2(\alpha)&\cos^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(\alpha)&\cos^2(\alpha)\\\sin^2(\beta)&\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\beta)&\cos^2(\beta)\\\sin^2(\gamma)&\cos^2(\gamma)-\sin^2(\gamma)&\cos^2(\gamma)\end{vmatrix}=1\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\sin^2(\alpha)&\cos^2(\alpha)&\cos^2(\alpha)\\\sin^2(\beta)&\cos^2(\beta)&\cos^2(\beta)\\\sin^2(\gamma)&\cos^2(\gamma)&\cos^2(\gamma)\end{vmatrix}+(-1)\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\sin^2(\alpha)&\sin^2(\alpha)&\cos^2(\alpha)\\\sin^2(\beta)&\sin^2(\beta)&\cos^2(\beta)\\\sin^2(\gamma)&\sin^2(\gamma)&\cos^2(\gamma)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Wait a minute – we're not saying $\det(A+B)=\det A+\det B$, are we?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, of course not! What makes you think that? In fact, I'm not even sure whom you're addressing...

Comment: @Don, never mind, just a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Relate the third column to the first two using the trigonometric identity
$$\sin(\theta+\delta)=\sin\theta\cos\delta+\cos\theta\sin\delta.$$

Comment: That's what I said, innit?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess it pretty much is. Would you like the give the answer? I can delete this one.